# Error: <circle> attribute cx: Expected length, "NaN" for d3

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I am working on trying to make a simple scatterplot in d3, and I am having trouble getting the x scale working, but I am able to get the yScale working. Here is my code:

```
//Define the dataset to be used for this example
var dataset = [
                  [ 5,     20 ],
                  [ 480,   90 ],
                  [ 250,   50 ],
                  [ 100,   33 ],
                  [ 330,   95 ],
                  [ 410,   12 ],
                  [ 475,   44 ],
                  [ 25,    67 ],
                  [ 85,    21 ],
                  [ 220,   88 ]
              ];

//Define the width and height of the SVG
var w = 500;
var h = 100;


//Add the empty svg element to the DOM
var svg = d3.select(".myDiv")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

//Create the scales for the scatterplot
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { 
                    return d[0]; 
                })])
                .range(0, w);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
                    return d[1];
                })])
                .range([0, h]);



//Add the points to the scatter plot and size them accordingly
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(h - d[1]);
    });

//Add labels to the points to be able to see what the values are 
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d[0] + ", " + d[1];
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("font-size", "11px");
```

The weird thing is that the y scale works just fine, but I cannot see the difference between the xScale and the yScale that would make one work but not the other. Any ideas?

Comment: You got a type on your xScale range part .range(0, w); -> .range([0, w]);

Comment: God damnit. That always happens to me where I have some typo that is tiny but manages to break my code. I feel literally as dumb as rocks. Thanks for the help @getbuckts!

Comment: Just as a hint, I basically took your code, put it into an html page and ran it.  I then from debugger console just typed xScale(1) to see what I would get...NaN...of course but I got that for any number I typed so I figured there was a typo some where with your definition of xScale.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again for the help. I will try that in the future!